# Cakephp IN(x,x) with 'AND'

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find, cakephp-2.1

I am struggeling with a custom find in cakephp 2.1.

In my model I have this function:

```
public function findByGenres($data = array()) {
        $this->Item2genre->Behaviors->attach('Containable', array('autoFields' => false));
        $this->Item2genre->Behaviors->attach('Search.Searchable');
        $query = $this->Item2genre->getQuery('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Genre.name'  => $data['genre']),
            'fields' => array('item_id'),
            'contain' => array('Genre')
        ));
        return $query;
    }
```

This returns the following query:

```
SELECT `Item`.`id` FROM `items` AS `Item` 
     WHERE `Item`.`id` 
       IN(SELECT `Item2genre`.`item_id` FROM `item2genre` AS Item2genre 
          LEFT JOIN `genres` AS Genre ON(`genre_id` = `Genre`.`id`) 
              WHERE `Genre`.`name` 
                IN ('Comedy', 'Thriller')
         )
```

The result of the query returns Items with either 'Comedy' or 'Thriller' genre associated to them.

**How can I modify the query to only return Items with 'Comedy' AND 'Thriller' genre associated to them?**

Any suggestions?

*edit:*

content of data is:

```
'genre' => array(
                (int) 0 => 'Comedy',
                (int) 1 => 'Thriller'
            )
```

Comment: what is the content of `$data['genre']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want your `'conditions'` key to be this:

```
'conditions' => array(
    array('Genre.name' => 'Comedy'),
    array('Genre.name' => 'Thriller')
)
```

So specifically to your problem your `$data['genre']` is `array('Comedy', 'Thriller')`. So you could create a variable that has contents similar to what you need by doing:

```
$conditions = array();
foreach ($data['genre'] as $genre) {
    $conditions[] = array('Genre.name' => $genre);
}
```